# Creating a sample from multiple distributions and then finding deviation. What is the term?

Tags: standard-deviation, moments

I have 1000  gamma distributions, each with a different mean but constant ratio :$$\frac{mean}{s.d.}$$ also known as coefficient of variation. I extract one sample from each. Then I calculate :  $$\Sigma_i\frac{|sample_i - mean\_of\_that\_distribution_i| }{ mean\_of\_that\_distribution_i} $$ I believe I cannot call this deviation. Is there a term for this?

Any suggestions on how to analyse the samples?